# Reduce brightness when inactive for X minute - Desktop

Tags: screen, touchscreen

I use a desktop station to run an app for customers, I want to reduce the brightness after X minutes by Y% (not switching off the screen).
I can't get that in my desktop. I can get the dim function working.
Is there any solution ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Script to dim the screen after x seconds

The script below will dim the screen after an arbitrary number of seconds if the computer is idle (no input from mouse or keyboard)

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time
import sys

# read arguments from the run command: idel time (in seconds
dimtime = int(sys.argv[1])*1000
# brightness when dimmed (between 0 and 1)
dimmed = sys.argv[2]

def get(cmd):
    # just a helper function
    return subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8").strip()

# get the connected screens
screens = [l.split()[0] for l in get("xrandr").splitlines()
           if " connected" in l]

# initial state (idle time > set time
check1 = False

while True:
    time.sleep(2)
    # get the current idle time (millisecond)
    t = int(get("xprintidle"))
    # see if idle time exceeds set time (True/False)
    check2 = t > dimtime
    # compare with last state
    if check2 != check1:
        # if state chenges, define new brightness...
        newset = dimmed if check2 else "1"
        # ...and set it
        for scr in screens:
            subprocess.Popen([
                "xrandr", "--output", scr, "--brightness", newset
                ])
    # set current state as initial one for the next loop cycle
    check1 = check2
```

#### How to use

1. The script needs `xprintidle`:

   ```
   sudo apt install xprintidle
   ```
2. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `dimscreens.py`
3. Test- run it from a terminal, with the idle time and the desired brightness (dim state) as arguments:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/dimscreens.py 20 0.6
   ```

   where the script dims the screen after 20 seconds to 60% brightness.
4. If all works fine, add to Startup Applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add the command:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "sleep 10 && python3 /path/to/dimscreens.py 20 0.6"
   ```

#### Explanation

An easy way to set screen brightness for your purpose is (e.g. 50%):

```
xrandr --output <screenname> --brightness 0.5
```

The script uses [xprintidle](http://www.unix.com/man-page/debian/1/xprintidle/) to periodically get the current idle time, comparing it to the last cycle:

```py
while True:
    time.sleep(2)
    t = int(get("xprintidle"))/1000
    check2 = t > dimtime
```

If either the time exceeds the set time *or* jumps back to unidle, the script takes action:

```py
if check2 != check1:
    newset = dimmed if check2 else "1"
    for scr in screens:
        subprocess.Popen([
            "xrandr", "--output", scr, "--brightness", newset
            ])
```

...setting either the brightness to 1 (=100%) or the set dim-brightness.

More detailed explanation on the code is in the script.

#### Note

As it is, the script dims all screens . If you need to set only one screen, all is possible.

Comment: I get this error when I run it : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dimsceen.py", line 6, in <module>
    dimtime = int(sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @user2997418 You need to set the time and the dim percentage, like in the example. The error message means you didn't :) (neither of them) `python3 /path/to/dimscreens.py 20 0.6` mind the **20 0.6**

Comment: @cl-netbox the message means the time nor dim percentage are set :) Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

### Wayland way

Thanks to @jacob-vlijm here is a modified script for Wayland users.

I use it for my odroid m1 device with touchscreen, so I only need to control one screen.

### Explanation

Usage: `./dimscreen.py backlight 5 20`

- backlight - name of screen, get it from `brightnessctl -l`
- 5 - seconds until idle
- 20 - value between 0 and 255 for brigthness, see also `brightnessctl -l`

Old brightness value is saved and restored, not just full brightness.

You need to install package `brightnessctl`.

Because brightnessctl needs root privileges, set suid bit to run it as normal user:

```
sudo chmod u+s /usr/bin/brightnessctl
```

`xprintidle` has been replaced by `dbus-send`, thanks to https://askubuntu.com/a/1231995/801283

### Script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time
import sys

# screen to dim
screen = sys.argv[1]
# read arguments from the run command: idel time (in seconds)
dimtime = int(sys.argv[2])*1000
# brightness when dimmed (between 0 and 255)
dimmed = sys.argv[3]

def get_cmd(cmd):
    return subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)

def set_cmd(cmd):
    subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)

get_idleTime = "dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor /org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor.GetIdletime"
get_brightness = "brightnessctl -d " + screen + " g"
set_brightness = "brightnessctl -d " + screen + " s "

# initial state (idle time > set time)
check1 = False
oldBrightness = "255"

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    # get the current idle time (millisecond)
    idleTime = int((get_cmd(get_idleTime)).communicate()[0].rsplit(None,1)[-1])

    # see if idle time exceeds set time (True/False)
    check2 = idleTime > dimtime
    # compare with last state
    if check2 != check1:
        # if state chenges, define new brightness...
        newBrightness = dimmed if check2 else oldBrightness
        oldBrightness = get_cmd(get_brightness).communicate()[0].rsplit(None,1)[0]
        # ...and set it
        set_cmd(set_brightness + newBrightness)
    # set current state as initial one for the next loop cycle
    check1 = check2
```