# xprintidle on Ubuntu Wayland

Tags: 18.04, 17.10, gnome-shell, 20.04, wayland

Anyone know if there is a version of `xprintidle` for Ubuntu running Wayland?

If not, what is the alternative to figure out the user idle-time like `xprintidle` does in milliseconds under Wayland?

It's interesting that the application is still in the repository when it is now essentially broken with Wayland.

Comment: The application is still in the repository probably because you can also use X.Org on 17.10.

Comment: Any idea on how to get the same response running Wayland?  Don't really want to use X

Comment: Looks like a breakthrough for Gnome desktops using Wayland...
"dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor /org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor.GetIdletime".  Will do more testing with different distros when time permits...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple answer to close this thread off.  It should solve all xprintidle issues on Wayland or X when using Gnome!

You can run in the command line:

```
dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor /org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor.GetIdletime
```

If you want just the integer value then you can use python3...

```
import subprocess

def get(cmd):
        return subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)

get_idleTime = "dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor /org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor.GetIdletime"

idleTime = int((get(get_idleTime)).communicate()[0].rsplit(None,1)[-1])

print(idleTime)
```

Comment: Good, may be this question should be tagged *gnome-shell*, the answer is DE specific.